# Samsung galaxy 5 mp3 player as dev device

Tags: android, testing

Can anyone attest to the usefulness of Samsung Galaxy 5.0 Android MP3 Player as device for dev testing? Not sure if this is up-gradable to android 4.x, but I'm thinking about getting it for dev testing if nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general any android device is suitable for developing, so this one is too.

Two issues I found by skipping over the tech details which may or may not matter to you, depending on what you intent to develop:

- It comes with Android 2.2.

  That's a kinda old android version *(released in may 2010 - see [platform versions](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) for a current version distribution on devices)*. Some people consider it the bare minimum target api when writing new apps. Samsung might update it, but in my experience believe that at the point the update is really available. Lot's of android update promises have been broken or delayed to eternity.

  If you want to play with newer API features as well, this might limit you a bit. Chances are that some custom ROMs will come out and you can update it to a newer version by flashing the device, but that's just a chance and will void your warranty. So take this with a grain of salt. Check [xda-developers.com](http://xda-developers.com) in a while if you want to go this way, they usually have all the things you need for that.
- It's not a phone

  Sounds weird, but well. Depends on what you want to develop. If you go for games or a calendar app for example, that's fine. But testing your self-written dialer or SMS replacement app is very limited since you can't access phone hardware.

If I would have to buy a new device I'd go for one of the allround flagship products, e.g. a highend phone like the Galaxy SII or the "google reference implementation", a Nexus device. These have almost all hardware features that you will encounter in the wild, so you can test as much as possible.

But if you just want to start android dev, don't want to spend more money and/or the limitations above don't matter too much to you, go for it.

Comment: ... my sentiments exactly, I just need something with a mobile browser and android basics, even if they're limited.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Galaxy Player 5.0 as a development device, and so far it worked well. If you're not looking for any phone related or latest Android SDK features, it can be a great device. 
Another selling point is a large bright screen: it helps you to test your design on the larger resolutions than most of available phones.
I've also tried Player 4.0, which should be a smaller version of 5.0, and there I discovered some issues with Google Play filters ([Samsung Galaxy Player 4.0 permissions filter on Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320269/samsung-galaxy-player-4-0-permissions-filter-on-google-play))