# Samsung Galaxy Player 4.0 permissions filter on Google Play

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, samsung-mobile

My app does not show up on Samsung Galaxy Player 4.0 in Google Play (ex-Android Market).

If I sign in through the Play web interface, I get the error message: "This app is incompatible with your Samsung YP-G1. Samsung YP-G1 This item is not compatible with your device.". The same device was used for development, and there were no problem running app on it. App uses somewhat minimal set of permissions, and so far I did not have any problem with filtering on the Google Play. I was able to install app on Samsung Galaxy Player 5.0 without any problems from Google Play, so hopefully it is not related to Samsung.

Does anybody have any idea what to look for? Player 4.0 can be an excellent device for my app since it can run on Wi-Fi only without phone contract.

Here is a part of AndroidManifest related to permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" android:required="false"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
```

Output of $ aapt dump badging

```
uses-permission:'android.permission.CAMERA'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.VIBRATE'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.vibrate'
sdkVersion:'7'
targetSdkVersion:'7'
...
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.landscape'
main
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

Comment: the only thing unusual I see is `android.hardware.screen.landscape`

Comment: it looks like it's coming from declaration of Barcode Scanner activity: ...android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity....android:screenOrientation="landscape"....

Would I need a permission for Landscape mode?

Comment: There is no permission for landscape mode but `uses-feature` (w/o `required="false"`) means that the device has to support landscape mode and in case Samsung does not state that it can it could potentially lead to the behavior you observed. E.g. tablets that don't have a back-facing camera will be excluded from apps that require the camera-feature (which is back-facing only) although they have a front-facing camera.

Answer (score -1):

Remove permission for camera in manifest page. Then upload to google play, then check it will work and  will be shown in google play.